# Creating buttons with different images and CSS

Tags: css, image, performance, button, css-sprites

I got kind of a tricky question. I want to create some buttons which look a bit like this.

[image]

Now as you can see all buttons share the same background, a rounded rectangle, and inside some different pictures and text.

So should I just make a huge spritemap with all buttons or is it better (for performance) if I create a link with the background picture of the rounded rectangle and then place the images and text inside using CSS?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using [compass](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/) or something like that to make the sprites so that you can have 2 resolutions for high dpi screens. As for the rounded rectangle, you would just do that with CSS and then position the background image inside of it. --- [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/s4Ggu/) --- On the other hand, if this isn't a site for a nursing home or small children, you might want to just use icon fonts. I don't know how much a little drawing of a picture frame really has anything to do with uploading an image.

### HTML

```
<a href="#" class="box">
    <div class="sprite-icon"></div>
    <h2>Add user</h2>
</a>
```

### CSS

```
.box {
    display: block; /* because it's a link and we want to put things in it | could be inline-block*/
    text-decoration: none; /* remove default */
    color: inherit; /* remove default */
    width: 8em; /* arbitrary */
    border: 1px solid #333; /* backup */
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 1em;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.box .sprite-icon {
    display: inline-block; /* as to center */
    width: 6em;
    height: 6em;
    background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/120/120");
}

.box h2 {
    margin: 0; /* remove default */
    padding: 0; /* remove default */
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: arial;
    color: #2695dc;
}
```

Comment: appriciate it
will it boost the performance a bit or does it make no real difference ?

Comment: I choose never to use sprites, but what is happening - is that you are making an http request for each individual image vs 1 http request. - So yes, it is "faster." You should make 2 versions and test in dev tools and watch what happens. I bet it's not a huge difference... but if you are amazon.com or something... every millisecond counts.

Answer (score 0):

Create the button, including the text, gradient, border, drop shadow, inner box shadow (the white highlight) with css, and place the image in the middle using a sprite map. You'll need to space each spite fairly distant from each other, but it should work well.

Once you've created the spite map, I would strongly suggest running it through [ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Google just uses [one giant image](http://www.google.com/images/nav_logo170.png) with many icons because that is better for performance.
Combine everything in one giant image unless you're feeling lazy.

Really, though, you could do the border radius and box shadow with CSS.

Comment: Is it just me or are all of those images really crappy? Like the google logo on google maps - can make any site look 14 years old.

Comment: @sheriffderek is your browser zoom at 100%? Most of the images look pretty good to me.

Comment: My browser is at "Actual size." Maybe it's just a personal taste issue.

Comment: @sheriffderek maybe :) I still don't know what Google maps logo you don't like.

Comment: See the 3rd figure down: http://designshack.net/articles/html/embedding-google-maps-into-a-web-page-a-beginners-guide/

Comment: It's the rainbow "POWERED BY Google" one. It's not retina ready and always looks low quality.

Comment: Generally... a company as big as google should have upgraded to their own super rad icon-font over a year ago.

Comment: @sheriffderek on the Google Maps preview, there is no longer a "powered by Google" text. Instead, they replaced it with a grayscale version of the Google logo. :)

Comment: Hooray!!! but... the grey one is still pretty obnoxious. I'm not against them having credit... I think google is awesome - and I don't offer a solution yet, but what they have now is still no good.

Comment: @sheriffderek I personally like it. But everyone can have their own personal preference -- I've got nothing against that. :)

Comment: The problem for me, is that it is so specific. Not only is it a specific font that may clash with your own type faces, but it has a white drop shadow that could clash and the padding from the corner can clash and the edges just seems like such low resolution for reasons I can cannot explain. I would like it better if it were really large and I could choose the padding. Oh well. I just use a nice static image that links to the full google map page. It's better for performance anyways. Then I get to match to my style. Oh well. I'm glad you enjoy their logo. I wish I did.